# Why is division's answer wrong in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm fifteen and I'm new in this job.I try to learn this language for my future life.I entered 1,2,3,4,5. Finally  he says conclusion is zero  i searched but i couldn't find anything.can you help me please.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace Project3
    {
        internal class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //variable assigment
                int evennumber = 0;
                int oddnumber = 0;
                float ratio;
                //its for get numbers
                for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter" + i ". number : ");
                    int number=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                     //its for determine even and odd number
                    if (number%2 == 0)
                    {
                        evennumber = evennumber + number;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        oddnumber = oddnumber + number;
                    }
    
                }
                
                 ratio =evennumber/oddnumber;
                Console.WriteLine("Ratio : " + ratio);
    
    
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're dividing an integer by an integer, which means it's using integer division. The division operator's answer is correct; it's your expectations which are wrong.

Comment: Therefore, try to convert the numbers to float before dividing

Comment: @JosephDoggie In this case a cast would probably suffice

Comment: Yes, cast would be a better choice.  I was using "convert" in a somewhat general way